# React Native Config with separated build configurations doesn't work with Xcode Archive

Tags: xcode, react-native, environment-variables, react-native-config, xcode-archive

After making the **Xcode archive** and publishing it to **TestFlight internal testing**, my app is loading with **debug environments** - however the **Archive** has been done with **Release** and/or **Staging** scheme which theoretically should automatically load the release/staging **env file**.

It works fine on launching the app on real device: I choose the Release schema, chose my physical iPhone and press Run, after which Application is successfully launched with release environment variables. That's why I ignored the following section from the react-native-config documentation:

> ```
> In the Xcode menu, go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme
> Click Duplicate Scheme on the bottom
> Give it a proper name on the top left. For instance: "Myapp (staging)"
> Make sure the "Shared" checkbox is checked so the scheme is added to your version control system
> ```

This is my Podfile:

```
ENVFILES = {
  'Debug' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/../../.env.debug',
  'Staging' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/../../.env.staging',
  'Release' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/../../.env.production',
}

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.name == 'react-native-config'
        config.build_settings['ENVFILE'] = ENVFILES[config.name]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a reason why Archiving doesn't load the required env files depending on the selected Schema, while running application on real device does so?

Thank you mates in advance!